# Need Code coverage info of Source code dlls for MS UI automation

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, microsoft-ui-automation

We have a Winforms app which is 10 years old, and has a huge codebase in the UI layer. Writing unit test cases through NUnit or MS test would be a nightmare.

So we have opted for UI automation rather than white box testing.

Now the difficult part is, we need code coverage info of source code.

Is there any way through which I can get the source code executed/coverage of UI automation?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio has a built-in code coverage measurement tools. There are 2 options.

- You may create so called "generic test(s)" that run(s) your test system with necessary params. In such a case you need to create a test project, to create a test run configuration and to do many other things through a "Test" menu (VS 2015 Professional contains such a menu, previous versions may require Test System or Enterprise).
- Another option is using the tools from command line as described in [the MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd299398(v=vs.90).aspx#Anchor_2).

  - Use `vsinstr -coverage <myassembly.exe>` to instrument target binaries.
  - Use `start vsperfmon -coverage -output: mytestrun.coverage` to start collecting coverage data.
  - After the tests are finished just open `.coverage` file in Visual Studio (coverage should be perfectly highlighted in the source code editor as well).

Comment: Thanks worked, but did not get how to analyse the code Coverage File generated as output. Its looks like encoded file. Any editor/approach if know to analyse it?

Comment: Did you try opening it as a file while your solution is open?